# Local network install ubuntu desktop 12.04LTS 64BITS

Tags: networking, system-installation, pxe

I have an All In One PC without CDROM, and the USB ports are not working properly. I'm trying to perform a network installation via netboot/pxe, but it seems to be pretty difficult. I didn't have so many troubles with other distributions with the same procedure.

**Question:**

- Does the installation CD work as network repo via http or should I download something else?
- Where can I find accurate documentation?

Comment: This is a good read to start with.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server_and_network_installations